# Error during retrieving netsuite search result

Tags: netsuite, mule-component

I am trying to search a contact from netsuite. what i basically do is, creating a search criteria with email as parameter and trying to retrieve the result and then map it to object to xml transformer. But I am getting following error as :

*Could not call java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject() : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action*

The mule flow i am using as follows:

```
<flow name="contact_searchFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/basicContactSearch" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="Test1" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<component class="netsuitews.ContactBasicSearchComponent" doc:name="Search Contact Basic criteria"/>
    <logger message="Test 2" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<netsuite:search config-ref="NetSuite__Request_Level_Authentication" searchRecord="CONTACT_BASIC" fetchSize="5" doc:name="Contact Basic Search"/>
    <logger message="Test3" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <logger message="Test4" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

The search component i am using as follows:

```
public class ContactBasicSearchComponent implements Callable {

public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    ContactSearchBasic searchCriteria = new ContactSearchBasic();       

    SearchStringField nameFilter = new SearchStringField();
    nameFilter.setOperator(SearchStringFieldOperator.IS);
    nameFilter.setSearchValue("test_shutterFly@gmail.com");
    searchCriteria.setEmail(nameFilter);

    return searchCriteria;
}
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

I am using NetSuite Connector (Mule 3.5+)   version 7.1.0.201603151241 and running in mule 3.8.0 EE version.

Here is the stack trace i got from mule logs.

```
2016-08-18 20:41:26,181 [netsuitews].HTTP_Request_Configuration.worker.01] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - Test1

2016-08-18 20:41:26,194 [[netsuitews].HTTP_Request_Configuration.worker.01] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - Test 2

2016-08-18 20:41:37,668 [[netsuitews].HTTP_Request_Configuration.worker.01] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - Test3

2016-08-18 20:41:43,761 [[netsuitews].HTTP_Request_Configuration.worker.01] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 

********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not call java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject() : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action
-------------------------------
message             : Could not call java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.writeObject()
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action

(com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException).
Payload               : org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator@7dbf934e
Element XML           : <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"></mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer>
Payload Type          : org.mule.streaming.ConsumerIterator

Element               : /contact_searchFlow/processors/5 @ netsuitews:customer_crud.xml:61 (Object to XML)
```

---

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot marshal the XStream instance in action
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.SelfStreamingInstanceChecker.marshal(SelfStreamingInstanceChecker.java:59)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:226)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:189)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:135)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:83)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
at     
.
.
.
```

Could you please help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That conversion exception occurs because the NetSuite **Search** operation is a processor that implements **Pagination**. Therefore, the resulting payload is of  type **ConsumerIterator**. The **Object to XML** transformer cannot directly convert that iterator to XML. You need to extract its contents first in order to manipulate it. One option is to convert the data to a List and then apply the XML transformer. For example:

```
#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)]
```

Then your flow would look like this:

```
<flow>
    ...
    <netsuite:search config-ref="NetSuite__Request_Level_Authentication" searchRecord="CONTACT_BASIC" fetchSize="5" doc:name="NetSuite"/>
    <set-payload value="#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
</flow>
```

Additionally, I suggest you use DataWeave to build the input data for NetSuite instead of using the Java component to set the search criteria.

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
    %output application/java
    ---
    {
        email: {
            operator: "IS",
            searchValue: "test_shutterFly@gmail.com"
        }
    } as :object {
        class : "com.netsuite.webservices.platform.common.ContactSearchBasic"
    }
    ]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

The final flow would look similar to:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are right @CountD. It works like a charm.